# null pointer exception on retrieving records from the database hibernate hql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have a record that exists in my database which I crossed several times and the record is correct. I have also ensured that toString is overriden in my class to get a meaningful representation of the data I am retrieving.

This is the hql I am using to fetch records from the database

```
public List <Admin> getByAdminRole(int id) {
        Query query = _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("select a.id from Admin a WHERE a.id = :id");
        query.setParameter("role", id);

        return  query.list();
      }
```

In my controller class I am calling the hql method this way

```
SupportDao _supportDao = new SupportDao();
            List <Admin> add = _supportDao.getByAdminRole(1); //this line of code throws null pointer exception

            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> the value of add>>>>>>> " + add);
```

After research on solving nullpointer exception, I have ensured that toString is overriden in my model class Admin.java

```
@Override
    public String toString(){

        return this.id + this.name + this.getEmail() + this.getPassword() + this.role;
    }
```

Please what could be wrong with my code?

Comment: Please post whole stacktrace

Comment: Which line is SupportDao.java:140? can you indicate this in the code?

Comment: You are also trying to convert List<Integer> into List<Admin> and also change query.setParameter("role", id); to query.setParameter("id", id);

Comment: what result you want **List of Admins** or just  **Admin**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're instantiating `SupportDAO` yourself are you **absolutely, 101% sure** that `_sessionFactory` in `SupportDAO` is also instantiated?

Comment: And the same with `getCurrentSession()`?

Comment: @Francis still you need to change setParameter statement and casting

Answer (score 2):

change

`query.setParameter("role", id);`

to

`query.setParameter("id", id);`

if want to return `List<Admin>` also modify ,

`.createQuery("select a.id from Admin a WHERE a.id = :id");`

to

`.createQuery("from Admin a WHERE a.id = :id");`

**it will return Admin list with only one Admin if single id is present**

**if you want single Admin then**

`return query.uniqueResult();` and change return type as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your above code where you passing the **"id"** as parameter but in setParameter method your are passing with **"role"** .

I guess you need to pass it with **"id"** only.